# jQuery CSS how to avoid flickering?

Tags: jquery, css

I'm doing this to apply some style on a classical table (classical table = `tr` with *only* `th` or `td` in it.

```
$('table').css({
        'border-collapse': 'collapse',
        'margin': 'auto'
    })
    .attr({ 'cellpadding': '5px' })
    .find('tr')
    .css({
        'border-left': '1px solid black',
        'border-right':'1px solid black'
    })
    .find('th')
    .parent()
    .css({
        'border':'1px solid rgb(50,170,180)',
        'border-left': '10px solid rgb(0,120,130)',
        'border-right':'10px solid rgb(0,120,130)',
        'font-size': '2em'
    });
```

The only problem is that this code is in a "`refresh()`" function. So when it's called, if nothing has changed in the table, there's still a "flicker" because the style it applies first is on all the '`tr`' then, *only after*, modify it for `tr` which contain `th` (through `parent()`) to show them 'bigger'.

In other words : `tr` which contain `th` cells have bigger display.
I want it not to flicker.

How would you do this?

Comment: Can't you call this only if something has changed?

Comment: Why not using any CSS rules instead?

Comment: Because I want it to be full jQuery (see http://www.doonoo.fr/)

Comment: You can still append/remove to DOM any  `<style>` tags, i'd go for it instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I've come up with is:

```
    /* select tr that contain only th and not td */
    el.find("tr:has(th):not(:has(td))").css({
        'border':'1px solid rgb(50,170,180)',
        'border-left': '10px solid rgb(0,120,130)',
        'border-right':'10px solid rgb(0,120,130)',
        'font-size': '2em'
    });
    /* select tr that contain only td and not th */
    el.find("tr:has(td):not(:has(th))").css({
        'font-size': '1.4em'
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use CSS for these styles, and then jQuery `.addClass` to dynamically apply them to elements if needed..